# Aplicar movimiento a RectF Canvas Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

Hola a todos espero estén bien, soy nuevo trabajando con canvas en android y tengo el siguiente problema.

Cree dos RectF para hacer un test

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mRectSquare.left   = 0;
    mRectSquare.top    = top;
    mRectSquare.right  = getWidth();
    mRectSquare.bottom = bottom;

    mRectSquare2.left   = 0;
    mRectSquare2.top    = top2;
    mRectSquare2.right  = getWidth();
    mRectSquare2.bottom = bottom2;

    if (mCircleX == 0f || mCircleY == 0f){
        mCircleX = getWidth() / 2;
        mCircleY = getHeight() / 2;
    }

    canvas.drawRect(mRectSquare, mPaintSquare);
    canvas.drawRect(mRectSquare2, mPaintSquare);
}
```

y mi evento Touch

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean value = super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            top    = event.getY();
            bottom = event.getY() + 6;

            postInvalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

El problema surge que no encuentro la forma de aplicar movimiento a cada RectF por separado es decir que solo se mueva cuando hago tap sobe el mismo, solo logro hacerlo con uno pero no con los dos.

Super agradecido.

Answer (score -1):

Para los que aun sigan buscando una solución, qui se las dejo lo que hice, la solución la otorgo el usuario @Triode yo solo ajuste el código a mi necesidad.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleDrag extends View {

private final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;
private final int mTotalItems   = 3;
private boolean isInitLine      = false;
private int mWidth, mHeigth;

private ArrayList<Rect>  mItemsCollection;
private ArrayList<Point> mActiveDragPoints;
private ArrayList<Rect>  mActiveRects;


private Paint mPaint;

/**
 * @param context
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    mWidth  = width;
    mHeigth = height;
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int width, int height) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mWidth  = width;
    mHeigth = height;
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int width, int height) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mWidth  = width;
    mHeigth = height;
    init();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    for( Rect rect : mItemsCollection){
        canvas.drawRect(rect, mPaint);
    }
}


/**
 * @param of type null
 * @return of type null
 * function which will initialize the view
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void init(){

    mActiveRects      = new ArrayList<Rect>(mTotalItems);
    mActiveDragPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(mTotalItems);
    mItemsCollection  = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    for( int i = 0; i < mTotalItems; i++){
        Rect rect = null;
        if ( i == 0){
            rect = new Rect(0, mHeigth / 2, mWidth, (mHeigth / 2) + 4);
        }else if ( i == 1){
            rect = new Rect(0, (mHeigth / 2) + 220, mWidth, ((mHeigth / 2) + 220) + 4);
        }else if ( i == 2){
            rect = new Rect(0, (mHeigth / 2) - 220, mWidth, ((mHeigth / 2) - 220) + 4);
        }

        mItemsCollection.add(rect);
    }
    mPaint     = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action  = event.getActionMasked();
    final int pointer = event.getActionIndex();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            Point touchDown = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            lookForIntersection(touchDown);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL :
            mActiveDragPoints.removeAll(mActiveDragPoints);
            mActiveRects.removeAll(mActiveRects);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            int count = 0;
            for(Rect rect : mActiveRects){
                Point curretPoint = new Point((int)event.getX(count), (int)event.getY(count));
                moveRect(curretPoint, mActiveDragPoints.get(count), rect);
                count++;
            }
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Rects" + mActiveRects.size());
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Points" + mActiveDragPoints.size());
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN :
            touchDown = new Point((int)event.getX(pointer), (int)event.getY(pointer));
            lookForIntersection(touchDown);
            //Log.d(getClass().getName(), "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN" + pointer);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :
            int index = getIntersectionRectIndex(new Point((int)event.getX(pointer), (int)event.getY(pointer)));
            if( index != INVALID_INDEX ){
                Rect rect = mItemsCollection.get(index);
                mActiveDragPoints.remove(mActiveRects.indexOf(rect));
                mActiveRects.remove(rect);
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * @param touchDown of type Point
 * @return of type null
 * function which will find the
 * intersecting rect and add to the
 * active collection
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void lookForIntersection(Point touchDown){
    final int index = getIntersectionRectIndex(touchDown);

    if( index != INVALID_INDEX ){
        final Rect rect = mItemsCollection.get(index);
        if( mActiveRects.indexOf(rect) == INVALID_INDEX ){
            mActiveDragPoints.add(touchDown);
            mActiveRects.add(mItemsCollection.get(index));
        }
    }
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Rects" + mActiveRects.size());
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Points" + mActiveDragPoints.size());
}




/**
 * @param point of type Point
 * @return of type int
 * function which will return the index of
 * the rect contaning the given point
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private int getIntersectionRectIndex(final Point point){
    int index = INVALID_INDEX;
    for(Rect rect : mItemsCollection){
        if(rect.top < point.y && point.y < rect.top +  40){
            index = mItemsCollection.indexOf(rect);
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}


/**
 * @param currentPoint of type Point
 * @param prevPoint of type Point
 * @param rect of type Rect
 * @return of type null
 * function which will move the change the
 * bounds of teh rect
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void moveRect(Point currentPoint, Point prevPoint, final Rect rect){
    int xMoved = currentPoint.x - prevPoint.x;
    int yMoved = currentPoint.y - prevPoint.y;
    rect.set(0, rect.top + yMoved, rect.right + xMoved, rect.bottom + yMoved);
//        rect.set(rect.left + xMoved, rect.top + yMoved, rect.right + xMoved, rect.bottom + yMoved);
        mActiveDragPoints.set(mActiveDragPoints.indexOf(prevPoint), currentPoint);
    }

}
```

Comment: respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, añade lo relevante del link aqui y solo deja la URL como referencia, adempas debes hacer una referencia completa del usuario original que dio la respuesta